# gcc build error : cannot find -lssl

Tags: linux, centos, make, gcc, scl

Hey all,
i am trying to build a project called *RamCloud* on `CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708`
this project specifically requires **gcc 4.9** and with my centos i only had **gcc 4.8** so i had to :

- completely remove gcc4.8 from my system `sudo yum remove
  --skip-broken gcc`
- install scl `sudo yum install centos-release-scl`
- install
  [devtoolset-3](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/sclo/x86_64/rh/devtoolset-3/)
  which includes **gcc4.9** `sudo yum install devtoolset-3`
- enable the devtoolset `scl enable devtoolset-3 bash`

that helped with some errors i had before, but now when i try to run `sudo make -j12` to build the project, i get errors related to the **devtoolset**
this is what the error looks like :

> /opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/ld:
>   **cannot find -lssl**
>   /opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/ld:
>   **cannot find -lcrypto**
>   **collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**
>   **make: [obj.master/apps/client] Error 1**
>   **make: Waiting for unfinished jobs....**

i'm not sure but i think it's a linking problem, any one encountered this before ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both errors are related to the OpenSSL development libraries not being installed ( -lssl is a pretty dead giveway).

The `-lssl` can be divided into `-l`, meaning "link with", and `ssl`, which is the desired library gcc is asked to link in. Usually, the file to link in is named `lib<whatever_comes_after_the_-l>.a` and it needs the headers. The file and headers are in the dev (Debian-based) or devel (RPM-based) packages.
Here, ssl -> openssl, but you need development packages so it is either openssl-dev or openssl-devel.

So now you can search for the package that contains `lib<whatever_comes_after_the_-l>.a`. For Debian-based distributions, I install `apt-file`.

In Debian:

```
apt-file update
apt-file search libssl.a
```

In CentOS:

```
rpm -q -f libssl.a
```

In Debian/Ubuntu, to install them do:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

In CentOS, to install them do:

```
sudo yum install openssl-devel
```